# Check drupal 7 password to C#

Tags: c#, drupal-7, password-hash, phpass, cryptsharp

I am using CryptSharp official version for Checking drupal password hash but I am always getting false, Libarary doesn't have any direct documentation for drupal 7 password 7 but it is saying it has drupal 7 support on nuget description.

Using this code

```
Crypter.CheckPassword(password, hash);
```

Tested for following password and hash

```
Crypter.CheckPassword("admin123","$S$DlagvsBQGWTktiD4cAA2IHTLFzQw7pLuH4427TAq9QxK2b3xtJBT");
```

but result is always `false` and I am able to login in drupal by same hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 7 hashing is fixed in CryptSharp 2.1 and up.

Comment: Verified it is fixed now!